# Using Green's function in Cauchy problem

Tags: greens-function, cauchy-problem

Green's function is a well known tool for solving differential equations with boundary conditions by turning it into integral equations. I wonder if Green's function can be applied somehow in a Cauchy problem for ODEs. I suppose that the answer is no, because a Green's function construction procedure depends on boundary conditions. In this case, Is there a similar tool for solving a Cauchy problem for ODEs?